# Save and New Button will not clear fields

Tags: button, salesforce, visualforce, apex

I have 3 custom visual force pages. a view which views the record, edit which edits and a new that makes a new record.  Edit and New have a save and new button.  When I click save and new I need a redirect, a new record to be made, and few of the fields to be cleared however all the previous data is being transferred over on the redirect.

My apex code..

```
public PageReference saveAndNew() {  

    try {
        // Save the current sObject  
        sController.save();   
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult describeResult = sController.getRecord().getSObjectType().getDescribe();  
        // Create PageReference for creating a new sObject and add any inbound query string parameters.  
        PageReference pr = new PageReference('/' + describeResult.getKeyPrefix() + '/e?' + queryString);  
        // Don't redirect with the viewstate of the current record.  
        pr.setRedirect(true);  
        eventPackageRevenueBreakdown = new eventPackageRevenueBreakdown__c();
        eventPackageRevenueBreakdown.Name = null;
        eventpackageRevenueBreakdown.AdminIsIncludedInInclusivePrice__c = false;
        return pr;  
    } catch(Exception e) {  
        // Don't redirect if something goes wrong. May be a validation or trigger issue on save.  
        ApexPages.addMessages(e);  
        return null;  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check [Using the transient Keyword](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_transient.htm). Mark data, which you don't want to be transferred, as *transient*.